# Image from html not rendered while converting it into JPG - IMGKit gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, wkhtmltoimage, imgkit

I want to convert an HTML page into JPG image using IMGKit gem and wkhtmltoimage-binary, In my HTML page, there is a `div` class whose background is an image (styled inline), While converting this HTML page, the div background image is not rendered and remaining styles and contents are rendered in the generated image. I also tried IMG SRC tag in HTML, the image is not rendered then also.

```
html = %Q[<html><body><div style="background-image: url('https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/thumb/4/47/Iron_Man_(circa_2018).png/250px-Iron_Man_(circa_2018).png')">Vanakkam</div></body></html>]

kit = IMGKit.new(html,:height => 300,:quality => 50)

img = kit.to_img

img = kit.to_img(:jpg)

file = kit.to_file('file.jpg')
```

I can't figure out how to make this work and are there any methods in rails to complete this job?

Comment: Are you sure this works in normal view page ?(converting image ) and vanakkam means tamil?

Comment: Yup, This is working normally, few css tweaks are required, but the styling is working as it should be!

Answer (score 0):

Can you try to create your HTML page instead of using a string array?

Then you can just simply use `File.new` as the documentation suggests:

```
kit = IMGKit.new(File.new('/path/to/mysite.html'),:height => 300,:quality => 50)
```

Comment: Thanks for this idea, But I can't figure out where to put my HTML file from the documentation, I created a folder and changed the address towards it, but the file path is not accessible by File.new

Comment: I tried what you have suggested, still the image from html is not rendered!